# Последовательная сортировка массива

Tags: java

Суть задачи такова: отсортировать заданный массив. Если в сортированном массиве элементы повторяются, то относить один из повторяющихся элементов в конец массива. Таким образом в хвосте образуется вновь отсортированный массив. Если и в нем находятся повторяющиеся элементы, то повторяем вышеописанное действие и т.д.
Пример:

Входные данные:

```
40 20 30 10 30 20 10 20
```

Выходные данные:

```
10 20 30 40 10 20 30 20
```

Вот код.

```
ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer> (1000);
for (int i=0; i < 1000; i++){
    list.add((int)(Math.random()*1000) + 1);
}

Collections.sort(list);

int count, a, b;
do {
    count = 0;
    ArrayList<Integer> list2 = new ArrayList<Integer> (1000);
    for (int i=0; i < list.size()-1; i++){
        a = list.get(i);
        b = list.get(i+1);
        if (a == b){
            list2.add (list.get(i+1));
            list.remove(i+1);
            i--;
            count++;
        }
    }
    list.addAll(list2);
    if (list2.size() > 0){
        int first = list2.get(0);
        int size = 0;
        for (int i=0; i < list2.size(); i++){
            if (list2.get(i) == first) size++;
        }
        if (list2.size() == size) break;
    }
    list2.clear();
} while (count != 0);
```

Как можно заметить массив состоит из 1000 элементов. При таком условии сравнение двух соседних значений происходит только до значения 127 в массиве. Начиная со значения 128 проверка условия не проходит.

```
if (list.get(i) == list.get(i+1))
```

Вот что получается:

> 3 4 5 7 ... 119 121 122 124 128 128 128 131 132 132 ... 999 999 1000 4 11 16 ... 93 100 121 122 122.

А если вынести сравниваемые значения в отдельные переменные, как это сделано в первоначальном коде, то всё проходит нормально.

```
a = list.get(i);
b = list.get(i+1);
if (a == b){
```

Из-за чего так происходит и что можно сделать, дабы не вводить ради этого две новые переменные?

Comment: сделайте if (list.get(i).equals(list.get(i+1))), потому что вы сравниваете по ссылке, а надо по значению. А значения ( без опции -Djava.lang.Integer.IntegerCache.high) кеширует только значения до 127

Comment: @AndrewBystrov, гениально! Где тут лайк поставить? :)

Comment: Сейчас я добавлю ответ, там и можно будет лайк поставить

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В Вашем примере вы сравниваете 2 объекта по ссылке. Вам необходимо сравнивать 2 объекта по `equals`. Т.е. необходимо заменить

`if (list.get(i) == list.get(i+1))` на

`if (list.get(i).equals(list.get(i+1)))`.

Примитивные типы нужно сравнивать через `==` , а объекты нужно сравнивать через `.equals` ( за исключением, когда вам нужен один и тот же объект)

А то, что у вас значения сравниваються до 127, это потому, что у `java` для `int'ов` есть пул (и не только для int'ов) , который кеширует значения до 127. Если хотите увеличить это значение, то необходимо выставить опцию

> -Djava.lang.Integer.IntegerCache.high=999

и таким образом, значения до 999 будут закешированы в пуле, и ссылки на них будут одни и те же